# wsimport with basic authentication does not allow @ in username or password

Tags: web-services, wsimport

Question: I am trying to call wsimport tool for a webservice using basic authentication.
Unfortunately my password has @ char in it.

I tried the following :
I created a Authfile.txt with the following content in it.
http://username:pass@word@hostname:port/ws/mywebservice?wsdl

Note: The username and pass@word are the basic authentication credentials to access the web service.

And I ran the wsimport tool with the following options

wsimport -p com.example.ws -Xauthfile Authfile.txt -Xnocompile -keep -XadditionalHeaders -extension -B-XautoNameResolution http://hostname:port/ws/mywebservice?wsdl

wsimport tool throws the following error message.....
[ERROR] "http://username:pass@word@hostname:port/ws/mywebservice?wsdl" is not a valid authorization information format. The format is http[s]://user:password@host:port//

Answer (score 1):

Answer:
Change the contents of the Authfile.txt file by replacing  @ with %40 as follows:

http://username:pass%40word@hostname:port/ws/mywebservice?wsdl

And then I ran the wsimport as before

wsimport -p com.example.ws -Xauthfile Authfile.txt -Xnocompile -keep -XadditionalHeaders -extension -B-XautoNameResolution http://hostname:port/ws/mywebservice?wsdl

Now, it generated the java files with out errors.

I had spent more than couple of hours trying to fix this issue.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what if i have change it to %40 but still get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76394012/wsimport-throws-server-redirected-too-many-times-20